# xubuntu / lightdm doesn't detect display properly on first login but works on second login

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, lightdm

I have an xubuntu 20.04 PC connected to a 40" Samsung TV. Xfce / Lightdm is set to autologin. When it logs in, the detected display is wrong (it just says "default"), and the screen resolution is locked to 1024x768 according to Setting Manager -> Display. However, if I logout, then immediately log back in again, the display is correctly detected as 'Samsung 40"' and the resolution is correctly set to 1920x1080. I'm using the proprietary nvidia drivers (from Settings Manager -> Additional Drivers) for my GTX 960 card. I've tried the suggested tricks of putting "xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080" in the config, but that doesn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally figured this out. Apparently the nvidia drivers that ship with ubuntu are broken. An indicator of this was that the nvidia-setting app showed an empty window, even though nvidia-smi worked.

So to fix this issue:

1. In Settings -> Additional Drivers, select Noveau (just temporarily)
2. sudo apt-get install libglvnd-dev (needed by nvidia drivers)
3. Download the latest nvidia driver from their website
4. Switch to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)
5. Install the downloaded driver

   - Enable installing 32-bit compatibility libraries
   - Enable dkms
6. sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

   - add "blacklist nvidiafb"
   - add "blacklist nouveau"
7. reboot

If you happen to check Settings -> Additional Drivers, it will now show "manually installed driver" for the nvidia card.

Comment: Strange, since my XFCE works with the recommended Nvidia driver on a GTX 760 - maybe I'm just lucky....

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem and from last answer did work points 2 and 6.
After this I picked from Settings -> Additional Drivers Nvida prefered and tested, which in my case was update from 510 to 515. Reboot.
And working again.

Note in case drivers 510 or not performed update another solution is
install **lightdm-settings** and execute it once from Settings Manager. My case when updated nvidia drivers it just not worked some games (strange).

1. sudo apt-get install libglvnd-dev (but in my case probably I did not needed)
2. sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

   - add "blacklist nvidiafb"
   - add "blacklist nouveau"
3. sudo apt-get install lightdm-settings (in case installed lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings)
4. execute Settings Manager -> Login Window
5. reboot or sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service

Now, I would start it from 3 and later add 2 and 1.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234802)